# entity framework:selecting top level entity given condition on nested entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an object hierarchy like this:

```
(DbSet<Student>) Students
    -> (List<Semester>) Semesters
        -> (List<Module> Modules
            ->(List<Exam>) Exams
                -> (String) Result
```

How do i get all students who have a result which equals B

Comment: WhT have you tried so far? Is it any B or a B in a particular exam?

Comment: any semester, module or exam. I'm not entirely sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Context.Students.Where(student => student.Semesters.Any(semester => semester.Modules.Any(module => module.Exams.Any(exam => exam.Result == result)))));
```

That will get you students with any exam that is the result you want.